# How can a Interface be a variable within a class?

Tags: c#, interface

I'm trying to understand a class in a project and am a little confused about Interface's. 
From my understanding an Interface is a 'Contract' that a particular class will adhere to so that it shall always provide an implementation for the specified methods, properties etc.

So how is it possible that I can implement this as an Object? For example

```
private IMyInterfaceName _interfaceObject;
```

Could someone please explain what is the purpose of an interface as an object and how it might be used?

Comment: John Saunders gave the correct explanation. The above question doesn't answer my question as it explains what an interface is which isn't something I asked. I'm not sure why all the negative votes as my question was genuine and showed I already put research into what an Interface is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_interfaceObject` is able to hold a reference to an instance of a class which implements the interface:

```
public class MyClass : IMyInterfaceName {}
```

...

```
_interfaceObject = new MyClass();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a contract with two implementations :

```
interface ICalculator 
{
    //this contract makes it possible to add to given numbers a and b
    int Add(int a, int b);
}

class SmartCalculator : ICalculator
{
    // a concise way to add two numbers
    public int Add(int a, int b)
    {
        return a+b;
    }
}

class DumbCalculator : ICalculator
{
    //A not that beautiful way to add to numbers
    public int Add(int a, int b)
    {
        int result = a;
        for(var i=1;i<=b;i++)
        {
            result+=1;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Now the  class you're asking about

```
class MyMainClass
{
    private readonly ICalculator calcuator;

    public MyClass()
    {
        //If I'm smart i'll do the following
        calculator = new SmartCalculator();
        //If I'm not, well..
        calculator = new DumbCalculator();
    }
}
```